# Flutter-iOS: Is it possible to perform continuous operation in background state for iOS Application?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an Application related to IoT communication, where I connect my iOS applications with my IoT device(Smell detector device), and after the successful BLE connection, the IoT device will pass raw smell data continuously to my application via BLE.

Now the problem is I want my application to be connected with the device while the application goes to the background state and during the background state communication between App and IoT device should be remaining constant using a BLE connection. Also, I have to perform some calculations on the raw data received from the IoT device as well...

So Is there any way using which I can continuously get the data from the IoT device and perform some calculations on it while my app is in the background state?

Comment: If your sensor requires the app to issue read requests, no.  If the sensor indicates new data via BLE indicate/notify then yes, but if you perform too much calculation your app will be terminated.

Comment: @Paulw11 Actually the calculation is not too heavy but it continuous operation with no time limit... This means if the app is in a background state for 1hr or 2hr the app should be connected with the device using the BLE and receive the data continuously...

Comment: Also look up "state preservation and restoration".

Comment: @Emil I think `State preservation and restoration` will help if we need a last state of the app when it goes into background in my case requirement is to run a task continuously in backgroud.